# Adding tag description

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, review

I have just created a new tag. However, I'm not allowed to edit the tag description, it will need to be peer reviewed.

**If I have the permission to create a tag, wouldn't it make sense to also have permission to create the tag's description?**

This way, there will be less tags without description and less reviewing for moderators.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I disagree. It is very difficult to spam the site when creating tags (giving only the label). You only have 30 characters and it is quite difficult to get anything useful in there. Also, it will be noticed quite fast since the question gets enough eyes usually.

Tag wiki on the other hand are not that visible and very prone to spam (to a blog, some external source, or an 'advertisement' tag wiki). It won't get eyes automatically. Hence, it is important the tag wiki edits get reviewed.

There is something to say for tag creation with mandatory excerpt or wiki, but you have to keep in mind that the user creating the tag isn't necessarily someone with enough knowledge to write a good excerpt or wiki.

Comment: I understand your point. Wouldn't it be more consistent to have tag-creations reviewed as well then though? This would hardly be more work for moderators, as they will have to review the description anyway.

Comment: There is already a moderation page for 10K users listing all new tags. And any 2K user can review tag wikis.